# "Maximum update depth exceeded" in React functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with a react functional component. When the react-apollo query is "on completed" executes a code to handle a token, and when finish send to another page (using `history.push`).

When run the code I get a infinite loop with this message: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops`

1. I've tried comment `history.push` and the infinite loop does not happen again.
2. I comment all the logic in `list-session` component to avoid a recursive call, but it does not work (I checked thoroughly the code to confirm is not a recursive call).

I thing the problem is related with the lifecycle or with the history.push behavior

Ptt: I'm learning react on this moment

```
  const { setUserInfo, setUserId } = useContext(userContext);
  const { token } = match.params;

  const onCompleted = data => {
    if (data.validateUser.status) {
      setUserId(token);
      setUserInfo(data.validateUser.infoUser);
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      // history.push("/list-session");
    } else {
      history.push("/rare-page");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="Auth" data-testid="AuthPage">
      <Query
        query={VALIDATE_USER}
        variables={{ userId: token }}
        onCompleted={onCompleted}
      >
        {({ error }) => {
          if (error) return <Error />;
          return (
            <>
              <h2 data-testid="AuthState">Authenticating...</h2>
              <div className="spinner-border text-info" role="status">
                <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
              </div>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Added relevant code in the problem. I checked the component and no one of this make a recursive call, and no make a infinite *setState* call. The *setState* problem is the consecuence to another problem.

```
        <AnimatedSwitch
          atEnter={bounceTransition.atEnter}
          atLeave={bounceTransition.atLeave}
          atActive={bounceTransition.atActive}
          mapStyles={mapStyles}
          className="route-wrapper"
        >
          <Route exact path="/" component={NoCredentials} />
          <Route exact path="/token/:token" component={Auth} />
          <Route path="/list-session" component={Home} />
        </AnimatedSwitch>
```

and this is the code in Home component:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("activeSessions");

  return (
    <ValidateToken>
      <Container className="bg-light">
        <div className="Home">
          <CreateSessionComponent />
          <Nav tabs>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink
                className={classnames({
                  active: activeTab === "activeSessions"
                })}
                onClick={() => setActiveTab("activeSessions")}
              >
                Active Sessions
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
          <TabContent activeTab={activeTab}>
            <TabPane tabId="activeSessions">
              {activeTab === "activeSessions" && (
                <div>
                  <SessionsListComponent status="ACTIVE" />
                </div>
              )}
            </TabPane>
          </TabPane>
          </TabContent>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </ValidateToken>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Please share all the relevant code so we can help.

Comment: Check your component at `list-session` you might me calling setState inside a render method of that component or have recursive call somewhere within that component.

Comment: I think we need to see the component at `rare-page`

Comment: rare-page is a simple component that shows a message when the tokes status ( data.validateUser.status ) is not correct, the other code was added to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "maximum update depth exceeded" error occurs when you are trying to update a variable multiple times until the stack size exceeds. This usually happens when u are trying to set a state inside `render()` or calling a method inside render which in turn sets the state. So check if there is a `setState()` call inside render method of your code.
Also this might happen because of setting the `localStorage` variable inside render. Try to move it out of render. But if you anyways need it you can use the `componentDidMount()` hook. That way all your variables will be available to you when your component is rendered.

Comment: I was checking my code, in theory the only ```setState``` that i'm using is in the ```onCompleted``` method, in the ```list-session``` component does not use the ```setState```.

I am going to try with the ```componentDidMount()``` and tell us

Comment: any luck @KevinDarioAgudelo?

Answer (score 0):

try this it may work i think.

```js
<Query
  query={VALIDATE_USER}
  variables={{ userId: token }}
  onCompleted={(e)=>onCompleted(e)} //onCompleted throws an event
>
```